# Best pattern for saving and loading MobX store to React Native AsyncStorage?

Tags: javascript, react-native, mobx

I have a React Native app using MobX. My store has a default object, and when a user updates the value with an action (in an Options.js file), I'd like to then save this locally (React Native's AsyncStorage) so the next time the app is opened the object is not reset to default. What's a good pattern for handling this on first run, checking and loading new values?

My RootStore.js looks like this:

```
import { observable, action } from 'mobx';

export default class RootStore {
  constructor() {
    this.sources = new Sources(this);
  }
}

class Sources {
  constructor(rootStore) {
    this.rootStore = rootStore;
  }
  @observable
  left = [
    {
      active: 'yes',
      side: 'value One',
      name: 'value Two',
    },
  ];
//passing in new object from Options.js
  @action
  updateActiveLeft(data) {
    let object = data;
    this.left = object;
    console.log('New active name set in store - ' + this.left[0].name);
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've updated your file to include the basic pattern I've been using in all of my React Native applications. I'm using the async/await syntax to handle the async calls but you can use promises or whatever pattern you like. You may also want to make this a DRY class for handling all your local APIs. Note that this won't work if you store non-mobx methods in your stores since `mobx.toJS` doesn't remove them and `JSON.stringify` can't serialise functions.

EDIT: Fixed compile errors and added updateStore() method.

```
import { observable, action, toJS } from 'mobx';
import { AsyncStorage } from 'react-native';
import _ from 'lodash';

export default class RootStore {
  constructor() {
    this.sources = new Sources(this);
    // You can move this to your App.js class when your app
    // for more control but this will start loading your data
    // as soon as RootStore is created.
    this.sources.refreshStores();
  }
}

class Sources {

  @observable
  left = [
    {
      active: 'yes',
      side: 'value One',
      name: 'value Two',
    },
  ];

  //passing in new object from Options.js
  @action
  updateActiveLeft(data) { // May want to make this a promise or async
    let object = data;
    // this.left = object; // Now using updateStore to set MobX obs
    this.updateStore(toJS(object)).then(() => {
      console.log('Data is now saved in AsyncStorage.')
    });
  }

  /**
   * Set async data to local memory
   * @param newdata {object} An updated store abject
   */
  @action
  updateStore = async (newdata) => {
    try {
      const AppData = newdata;
      // Set MobX observables with new data
      _.forEach(AppData, (value, key) => {
        this[key] = value;
      });
      // Set AsyncStorage
      await AsyncStorage.setItem('app', JSON.stringify(AppData));
    } catch(e) {
      console.log('Could not update app store. [store/App]')
    }
  }

  /**
   * Set MobX data from AsyncStorage
   */
  @action
  refreshStores = async () => {
    try {
      const RootStore = await this.getStore();
      // I store my data in AsyncStorage exactly the same way I store my observables
      // so that when I recall them I can just iterate through my object or array
      // and set them easily to MobX observables.
      _.forEach(RootStore, (value, key) => {
        this[key] = value;
      });
    } catch(e) {
      console.log('Could not refresh app store.');
    }
  }

  /**
   * Retrieve data from AsyncStorage
   */
  @action
  getStore = async () => {
    try {
      // I'm just using RootStore as a storage key name but you can use whatever you want.
      // I'm also shortcircuiting the call to async to be replaced with the default values
      // in case the store doesn't exist.
      let RootStore = await AsyncStorage.getItem('RootStore') || JSON.stringify(toJS(this));
      RootStore = JSON.parse(RootStore);
      return RootStore;
    } catch(e) {
      console.log('Could not get data from store.')
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: Cool. I've added this (requires toJS from react-native and lodash, correct?). But I'm getting the "Could not get data from store" in the console.log...?

Comment: Ah sorry about that. Yes, it is lodash. Can you log the actual error in the catch statement for the getStore() method. `console.log(e);` should suffice.

Comment: Sure! 
TypeError: (0 , _reactNative.toJS) is not a function

Comment: Yet another dependency forgotten! Update your MobX import to look like this. `import { observable, action, toJS } from 'mobx'. All toJS() does is turn MobX observables into a real object/array that you can store. Otherwise, you will be storing the object MobX creates for you. Let me know if this works.

Comment: Cool -- this is now running without error. Console.log is showing success, but when reloading the app the new values are not loaded.

Comment: Awesome. You would just need to store whatever data you need into AsyncStorage. I modified my answer to show how you would store data using your updateActiveLeft example. I've also added a simple method for how you would continue using CRUD actions to modify both MobX and AsyncStorage.

Comment: Thanks!! This did the trick and it works well as a pattern for React Native AsyncStorage + MobX.

Comment: Would this method also work for deeply nested objects?

Comment: @AdamGerthel Yes. I am just loading key/values from local storage but these can be nested objects or multidimensional arrays. You may want to modify refreshStores() to fit your reactive clauses

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use `@save` decorator from [mobx-decorators](https://github.com/farwayer/mobx-decorators). But keep in mind `@save` is lazy decorator and value will be loaded after first property access.